# Check variable type with if statement

Tags: php

Hi I have a simple question regarding the array.

I am trying to use `foreach` loop to echo the `vars`. However, there are times that the `variable` wont' be an `array`
I have created a `if` statement to check the `variable` type, but I am not sure if it's the best practice doing it.

Are there any better way to do what I need? Thanks a lot!

My codes

```
$test = $_GET['testVar'];

if(is_array($test)){
 foreach($test as $t){
   echo $t;
 }
}else{
   echo $test;
}
```

Comment: Nope. That's how you would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_array` is the best way to check if a variable is an array. So your code is ok.

---

However here comes a generic solution that will work for all data types not just arrays with the function`gettype()`
You can refine the results if $type is 'Object' using the function `get_class()`

```
$type = gettype($var);

// get class name for objects if so desired
if($type === 'object') {
    $type = get_class($var);
}
```

Comment: I think OP is only concerned if it's an array; in which case `is_array` is perfectly suitable.

Comment: Ok maybe I misunderstood someting, however this is generic solution and should help in any case

Comment: Just stick to `gettype` and add that `is_array` is acceptable as well.

Comment: `get_class` doesn't work indeed. This is not JavaScript where everything is an Object-type :P. If you check for any type; use `gettype()` for unity. If you only check if it's an array, then use `is_array` as it returns a clean `TRUE`/`FALSE` :)

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk Thanks. Anwers to the easiest questions are most vulnerable for earning downvotes if not read 100% exactly ;) So I hope all are happy now :)